# Trying to figure out how to System.exit with a character

Tags: java, switch-statement, calculator, system.exit

I'm new at Java and coding and I'm trying to do a calculator where you type in the operation you want and then two numbers. 
The calculation is done inside a switch named "mth" but I cannot figure out how to exit my program using a character.

As you can see I have tried using,

```
if(op.equals("x")) System.exit(0);
```

but it seems that the program does not register it at all.

I have tried a number of things as using a boolean and playing around a bit but I can't get past this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("sv","SE"));
    Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Operation och två heltal (x för att avsluta)");

    while(op.hasNext()){

        if (op.equals("x")) {
        System.exit(0);
        }
        else{
        mth(op.next(), op.nextInt(), op.nextInt());
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
if (op.next().equals("x")) {
```

instead of

```
if (op.equals("x")) {
```

`op` is the complete `Scanner object`, so need to take the value out using `op.next()` from the `op` object and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you compare the Scanner with "x" and not the sign entered. You could use `String input = op.next()` and then `if (input.equals("x")) System exit(0);`

Edit: I think it is better to use an additional variable for this comparison as using `op.next()` twice might lead to unwanted results. By using an extra variable you can use `mth(input, ...)` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

op.equals("x") replaced with op.next().equals("x") or better "x".equals(op.next())